# what is the time complexity of this program?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm new to time complexity in algorithms.
   This is the code for counting the number of words in a text file.
   My problem is that every time my program prints one more than the actual count of words in the file, like if I have 11 words in my file it prints 12.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;   
/* main function  */
 void main()
 {
     ifstream inFile; //file file name
     string fileName;
      string word;
      int count = 0;
       inFile.open("example.txt");
         while(!inFile.eof())
           {
           inFile >> word;  
                   ++count;
               }
     cout << "Number of words in file is " << count<<endl; 
inFile.close();

}
//this file is for counting the number of words in a text file**
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing first : [*Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/1870232)  <sub>This will answer your extra count problem.</sub>

Then, coming to complexity, since it will go though every N words till it reaches end of file, it will be done in *O( N )* time

<sub>Also, `void main()` is not *legal* c++, main should return `int`</sub>